# Open pdf from byte array ios xamarin c#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a byte array that contains a pdf document and I want to open it in an ios application.

This is my code so far:

```
public static string WriteFileFromByteArray(string fileName, byte[] bytes)
    {
        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        var filePath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, fileName);
        File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, bytes);

        return filePath;
    }
```

Does any one know how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure where exactly you are stuck up.
But there is an issue in the below line of code you have posted.

`File.WriteAllBytes(**fileName**, bytes);//` on this code you are using filename instead of filepath.

Use `filePath` variable instead of `fileName` as it just contains the name of a file.

Refer the below link for PDF viewer.

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/631/open-a-pdf-with-the-built-in-pdf-viewer

Comment: Hi Kalyana, that is not a problem because the file name just indicates the name of the file I want to save to. I'm going to look at the link what you suggested in the link of xamarin forms. I'll be back to you. Thanks for now.

Comment: Hi Kalyana, you were right I used the filename in stead of path. I was busy for a long time and after a while you get blind for the smallest mistakes. Thank you anyway. To open the pdf, I used the solution provided here: https://gist.github.com/nicwise/5443188.

Comment: Great. It happens some time :)